# COM Port in use

Tags: port, com-port

When i am trying to install a particular software in break stating that `COM PORT 3` is in use and to stop any app that is using that. In Windows 7 PC

**Question**
How can I find which application is using the COM PORT 3

**I have tried below**

1. View Device manager with "show hidden devices" after setting up `"SET evmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1"`.
2. On "Process Explorer"  when i search for COM3 it shows a `svchost.exe`. It hosts `NAI Product Manager,WmiPrvSE.EXE`

but none worked.

*Please note*

I do not have privileges to modify the registry

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to determine what's using your COM port. Search for "serial" and that should get you in the right place. Not that it will list as \Device\Serial0. The number increments every time a new port is used, it does not reference the com port number.

By the way, what are you trying to install?

Comment: Yes did the same, I got Serial0 ,killed the process but still having the same issue. When i open the "Port Settings>Advanced>COM Port Number" it shows "COM3(in use)" but cannot find out what is using the same.
BTW I am trying to install "Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh.msi"